# Is there an expression that will return all siblings for a parent node in xslt

Tags: xslt, siblings

> For each 'paymentSummaries' section, a new table will be created and
>   I've been able to get this to work. What isn't working is getting the
>   paymentSummary/splitCode/(number)(type)(policyDetails)(amountPaid) to
>   display (return) more than just the first instance in each table.
>
> Here is my XML:

```
<paymentSummaries>
    <billingAccountNumber>billingAccountNumber1</billingAccountNumber>
    <paymentSummary>
      <splitCode>
        <number>paymentSummary1</number>
        <type>type1</type>
        <policyDetails>policyDetails1</policyDetails>
        <amountPaid>amountPaid1</amountPaid>
      </splitCode>
    </paymentSummary>
    <paymentSummary>
      <splitCode>
        <number>paymentSummary2</number>
        <type>type2</type>
        <policyDetails>policyDetails2</policyDetails>
        <amountPaid>amountPaid2</amountPaid>
      </splitCode>
    </paymentSummary>
    <serviceFee>serviceFee1</serviceFee>
    <totalAmountPaid>totalAmountPaid1</totalAmountPaid>
</paymentSummaries>
```

> This is what I've tried so far. The first example returns just the
>   first instance. The second example returns nothing/blank.
>
> **1st Example:**
>
> I have a `<xsl:for-each
>   select="SFF/*[local-name()='paymentReceipt']/*[local-name()='paymentSummaries']">`
>   wrapping around the entire table (this gets it to repeat the table for
>   each  that's passed.
>
> For the individual child and sibling elements, I haven't specified any
>   `<for-each>` or `<if>` tests because I thought it would just repeat the
>   instances.
>
> **2nd Example:**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <xsl:if test="SFF/*[local-name()='paymentReceipt']/*[local-name()='paymentSummaries']/*[local-name()='paymentSummary']/*[local-name()='splitCode'][1]/*[local-name()='number'] != ''">
<td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 8px 5px 0px 10px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="170" height="25" align="left" valign="top" class="fl wrap width150">
<div class="FS13 LH18" style="font-family: Arial Narrow, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#313131; font-weight:normal;">
<xsl:value-of select="SFF/*[local-name()='paymentReceipt']/*[local-name()='paymentSummaries']/*[local-name()='paymentSummary']/*[local-name()='splitCode'][1]/*[local-name()='number']"></xsl:value-of>
</div>
</td>
<td width="270" height="25" align="left" valign="top" class="fl wrap width150">
<div class="FS13 LH18" style="font-family: Arial Narrow, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#313131; font-weight:normal;">
<xsl:value-of select="SFF/*[local-name()='paymentReceipt']/*[local-name()='paymentSummaries']/*[local-name()='paymentSummary']/*[local-name()='splitCode'][1]/*[local-name()='type']"></xsl:value-of>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td width="95" align="right" valign="top" class="width150" style="padding: 8px 5px 0px 10px;">
<div class="FS13 LH18" style="font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#313131; font-weight:normal;font-family: Arial Narrow, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
       <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='paymentReceipt']/*[local-name()='paymentSummaries']/*[local-name()='paymentSummary']/*[local-name()='splitCode'][1]/*[local-name()='amountPaid']"</xsl:value-of>
</div>
</td>
</xsl:if>
</tr>
           <xsl:for-each select="*[local-name()='paymentReceipt']/*[local-name()='paymentSummaries']/*[local-name()='paymentSummary']/*[local-name()='splitCode'][position() >1]">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 8px 5px 0px 10px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="170" height="25" align="left" valign="top" class="fl wrap width150">
<div class="FS13 LH18" style="font-family: Arial Narrow, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#313131; font-weight:normal;">
            <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='number']"></xsl:value-of>
</div>
</td>
<td width="270" height="25" align="left" valign="top" class="fl wrap width150">
<div class="FS13 LH18" style="font-family: Arial Narrow, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#313131; font-weight:normal;">
           <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='type']"></xsl:value-of>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td width="95" align="right" valign="top" class="width150" style="padding: 8px 5px 0px 10px;">
<div class="FS13 LH18" style="font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#313131; font-weight:normal;font-family: Arial Narrow, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
          <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='amountPaid']"></xsl:value-of>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <xsl:if test="SFF/*[local-name()='paymentReceipt']/*[local-name()='paymentSummaries']/*[local-name()='paymentSummary']/*[local-name()='splitCode'][1]/*[local-name()='policyDetails'] != ''">
<td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0px 5px 8px 10px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="175" align="left" valign="top" class="fl wrap width150">
    <div class="FS13 LH18" style="font-family: Arial Narrow, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#313131; font-weight:normal;">
            </div>
    </td>
<td width="270" align="left" valign="top" class="fl wrap width150">
<div class="FS13 LH18" style="font-family: Arial Narrow, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#313131; font-weight:normal;">
    <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='splitCode'][1]/*[local-name()='policyDetails']" />
      </div>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </xsl:if>
 </tr>
<table>
```

> **This is what I'm getting** Table 1: paymentSummary1     type1    amountPaid1
>                        policyDetails1             (this table is missing paymentSummary2, type2, etc.)
>
> Table 2: paymentSummary3     type3    amountPaid3       (this table is
>   missing paymentSummary4, type4, etc.
>                        policyDetails3
>
> Any ideas how I can get this to work properly?

Comment: The XML data I showed isn't complete. I included 2 <paymentSummary> nodes for each <paymentSummaries> passed in the XML. It's the 2nd instance of the <paymentSummary> and the children of it that isn't displaying

Comment: Your XPath expressions refer to an element named SFF which doesn't appear in your XML examples, so I don't see how they can ever select anything. Also, (a) to understand XPath expressions, we need to know the context node when they are invoked, and (b) we need to know which version of XSLT this is.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can see what you are trying to do: put all of the payment summaries in a table followed by a single policyDetail

You start out by saying "For each 'paymentSummaries' section, a new table will be created ... "

So you want to start by doing that:

```
<xsl:template select='/'>
    <xsl:for-each select='//paymentSummaries'>
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='paymentSummary'/>
            <xsl:call-template name='policy'/>
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

next you ned to decide what you are going to do for each of the paymentSummary blocks. Here, I am just adding a new row to the table

```
<xsl:template match='paymentSummary'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select='splitCode/number'/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select='splitCode/type'/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select='splitCode/amountPaid'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Finally, I add the policy part: note the call-template instead of apply-template as I only want to do this once.

```
<xsl:template name='policy'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select='paymentSummary[1]/splitCode/policyDetails'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Once you have the general layout of what you want, go ahead and put in your own styling